# Get image download url from firebase storage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im trying to get the image url from a photo I uploaded to firebase storage so I can store the reference to the image in another table which will allow me to be able to display the image elsewhere throughout the app.

I currently have

```
private void UploadPhoto()
    {

        if (filePAth != null)
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.SetTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
            progressDialog.Show();

            var images = storageRef.Child("images/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            images.PutFile(filePAth)
                .AddOnProgressListener(this)
                .AddOnSuccessListener(this)
                .AddOnFailureListener(this);
        }            
    }


public async void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {

        try
        {
            var newImageDetails = storageRef.Child("images" + "/" + filePAth);
            Photo photos = new Photo();
            photos.categoryName = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
            photos.photoId = newImageDetails.Name;
            photos.ImageUrl = storageRef.DownloadUrl.ToString();
            photos.tagName = addTag.Text;

            if (user != null)
            {
                var uid = user.Uid;
                //set the users id to the category
                photos.uid = uid;
            }

            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
            var item = await firebase.Child("photos").PostAsync(photos);
        }
}
```

The storageref.DownloadUrl does not give me the correct url 
This is what I am looking for
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the trouble is Guid.NewGuid(). 
It generates a new code each time you insert a new image and your storageref points to it (image/GUID code).
In your OnSuccess you get image info from "images/" + filePath, that's different from upload path.
Why you use a new GUID? You can't determinate it, it will create a different path  each time.

Consider then that your download url contains the media token too, it's not simply the clean path as you expect

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution in debugging mode

i saw the downloadurl's properties and found the Scheme and SchemeSpecificPart

> Scheme = "https"
>
> SchemeSpecificPart = "//firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/maplog-e4ba5.appspot.com/o/-L0AMbihF23YKxsL1uss?alt=media&token=5c7ccef1-c857-4982-a288-fded2f0ff1aa"
> so here is my code:

```
void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var snapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;
    string imgUrl = snapShot.DownloadUrl.Scheme 
    + ":" 
    + snapShot.DownloadUrl.SchemeSpecificPart;
}
```

and it works! i was looking for the solution :(( but i finally found it myself XD